# How to generate data from a Hidden Markov Model(HMM) given the parameters of the model in R

Tags: hidden-markov-models, poisson

I have to generate data from a Hidden Markov Model.The data are modeled as a Poisson process with a parameter switching according to hidden Markov chain. With other words, `y_(k)|y_(k-1),r_(k)` distributed as a `Poisson(lambda_(r_k))`. 
The parameters of the model are`lambda=(0.5,2.5,5,8)`and the initial distribution and the transition matrix are denoted as `p0` and `p1` respectively in the algorithm below. My problem is that i do not know if my process below is correct or if there is any better way to obtain my data?

```
# -------Function RandomChoice------------
RandomChoice <- function( p){
  u=runif(1,0,1)
  if (u<=p[1]) return (1)
  else if (u<=p[1]+p[2]) return(2)
  else if (u<=p[1]+p[2]+p[3]) return(3)
  else  return(4)
}


# Create Data
TimeK = 100
NumState = 4
Iterations = 250
r=c()
y=c()
lambda=c(0.5,2.5,5,8)
p0=c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)

p1=matrix(c(0.28,0.64,0.05,0.03,0.36,0.46,0.1,0.08,0.06,0.14,0.43,
0.37,0.01,0.02,0.64,0.33), byrow=TRUE, nrow=4,ncol=4)
r[1]=RandomChoice(p0)
y[1]=rpois(1,lambda[r[1]])
for (k in 2:TimeK)
{
  r[k]=RandomChoice(p1[r[k-1],])
  y[k]=rpois(1,lambda[r[k]])
}
```

Comment: This seems correct to me :) (at least in essence as I am not an R programmer)